# Deleting Realm Objects that are part of other Realm Objects

Tags: android, realm

I started trying Realm for Android, so I created two classes:

```
class ProductSelection extends RealmObject {

private String selectedProductName;
private String selectedProductID;
…
}


class ProductProfile extends RealmObject {

private String profileTitle;   
private RealmList< ProductSelection > productSelection;
…
}
```

I then created a couple of ProductSelection Objects and ProductProfile Objects.

```
  realm.beginTransaction();
    ProductSelection prodSelection = realm.createObject(ProductSelection.class);
    prodSelection.setSelectedProductName(prodTv.getText().toString());
    prodSelection.setSelectedProductID(prodIdTv.getText().toString());
    …
    realm.commitTransaction();
    …
    realm.beginTransaction();

    ProductProfile profile = realm.createObject(ProductProfile.class);
    profile.setProfileTitle(“Some Title”);

    RealmResults< ProductSelection > results =         
    realm.allObjects(ProductSelection.class);
    RealmList< ProductSelection > selectionList = new RealmList<>();
    for (ProductSelection selection : results) {
    selectionList.add(selection);
    } 
    profile.setProductSelection(selectionList);

realm.commitTransaction();
```

Now I have the following questions:

1. When I call

   ```
   realm.allObjects(ProductSelection.class).clear();
   ```

it seems not only my ProductSelection Objects are cleared but also the List of ProductSelection Objects that are part of ProductProfile Class, as they now don’t hold any Objects anymore. Is it possible to prevent this, that is removing all ProductSelection Objects but still keeping the Objects that are part ProductProfile’s list?

2. Is the other way around also possible, that is removing ProductProfile Objects without removing ProductSelection Objects, that are not part of the productSelection List?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Realm is a typed database, so you can think of a RealmObject class a SQLite table. Clearing that, will remove all data, even if it is referenced from other classes.

The solution would be to make a query for the `ProductSelection` objects and delete those explicitly:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.where(ProductSelection.class).equalTo("someField", "someValue")
                               .findAll()
                               .deleteAllFromRealm(); 
        // deleteAllFromRealm() since 0.89.0, in previous versions it's `clear()`
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried deleteAllFromRealm(), it is removing items from result of query not from realm, because when I call get() it will return the same objects that I have deleted. What shall we do, please?

Answer (score 0):

I actually can't think of a **simple** way of supporting this explicit use-case, unless you use bi-directional mapping (if your `ProductProfile` class contains a `ProductSelection`, then that `ProductSelection` also contains its `ProductProfile`).

Because then you can do this

```
realm.where(ProductSelection.class).isEmpty("productProfileList").findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
// clear before 0.89.0, deleteAllFromRealm() after 0.89.0+
```

You have to manage this mapping yourself, though.